Vim cryptmethod with tmux not possible
I have noticed that when I want to encrypt a file in Vim
"Encryption -- use blowfish2
if has('cryptv') && v:progname != 'nvim'
    if has('patch-7.4.399')
    set cryptmethod=blowfish2
        else
        set cryptmethod=blowfish
        endif
endif

Then I can't open it when I use Tmux.  No password input is displayed.
:X
If I do not use Tmux or if I use zellij then it works.
What do I have to change in Tmux so that I can enter a password?

Is just the prompt missing (i.e. it works if you blindly enter the password) or does Vim not query the password at all? What happens instead? Do you get to see any file?

Yes, I can't see the input, i.e. nothing happens.
The file opens and I see the encrypted text.
The input is not there.
